# Why Room remove my database after migration

Tags: java, android, migration, android-room, database-migration

I want create new table in database. After migration app removed all items in database. Why? I haven't used `fallbackToDestructiveMigration()`

My code:

```
public class DatabaseClient {

private static DatabaseClient mInstance;
private DatabaseApp databaseApp;

private DatabaseClient(Context context) {
    appDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context, DatabaseApp.class, "DB_NAME").build();
    appDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context, DatabaseApp.class, "DB_NAME").addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2).build();
}

public static synchronized DatabaseClient getInstance(Context mCtx) {
    if (mInstance == null)
        mInstance = new DatabaseClient(mCtx);
    return mInstance;
}

public AppDatabase getAppDatabase() {
    return appDatabase;
}

static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(@NonNull final SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE `MarkRead` (`Id` INTEGER, `StudentId` TEXT," +
                "`StudentName` TEXT, `MarkId` INTEGER,`Mark` TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(`Id`))");
    }
};
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is because your old data has not been moved to the new table.

You will have to perform the following steps:

1. Create a temp table that you want to eventually CREATE.

`CREATE TABLE TEMP (... put your columns here)`

2. Fetch the results from your existing table by writing a "SELECT * " query.
3. Insert the results of the previous query into the Temp table.

`INSERT INTO TEMP SELECT .... FROM ORIGINAL`

4. Drop your existing table.

`DROP TABLE ORIGINAL`

5. Rename your temp table with the name of the existing table.

`ALTER TABLE TEMP RENAME TO ORIGINAL`

Now you will have a new table with the same name and the data as well.

Comment: thank you for your help. I did something like this.  [link](https://pastebin.com/RjBYZfcJ). The problem has not disappeared. After migration database is  empty :(